# Mysql Adonet ling Ms visual studio c#

Tags: mysql, .net, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I am trying to connect to the database using Ado.net ling. I get this error. How can I fix?. VS 2015. EF5.0 .MySQL

[image]

```
namespace ExamSystem
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

    public partial class DB_Exam_Entities : DbContext
    {
        public DB_Exam_Entities()
            : base("name=DB_Exam_Entities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<answer> answers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<correct_answer> correct_answer { get; set; }
        public DbSet<exam_archieve> exam_archieve { get; set; }
        public DbSet<exam_sub_subject> exam_sub_subject { get; set; }
        public DbSet<exam_subject> exam_subject { get; set; }
        public DbSet<exam> exams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<image> images { get; set; }
        public DbSet<question_type> question_type { get; set; }
        public DbSet<question> questions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<student_list> student_list { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is unreadable. Please insert your code and the error *as text*.

Comment: public DB_Exam_Entities db;
        private void AddSubjectForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //sh= new List<SubjectHeader>();
            db = new DB_Exam_Entities( );

            SubjectItemLoadComboBox();
        }